# What's the ruling on delaying Fajr azan?

Tags: salat, hanafi, adhan

In my country, which follows the Hanafi madhab, they give the Azan around an hour after fajr actually comes, not only that, but then they give the iqama around half an hour after the azan. Note they do it delibrately (I guess the government imposes on all masajid, but I think the government is muslim), they only do that on fajr salah. Is it allowed for them to delay either of the Azan and the Iqama?

Jazakum Allah khayran

Answer (score 1):

The Hanafis consider it recommended to delay Fajr. They do it based on the hadith of the Prophet ﷺ:

> أسفروا بالفجر فإنه أعظم للأجر
>
> Delay fajr till whiteness for it fetches the maximum reward.
>
> <sup>— [Nasai](https://sunnah.com/urn/1105510) , [Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/2/6)</sup>

References:

- [Al-Hidayah fi Sharh Bidayat al-Mubtadi](https://archive.org/stream/Hedaya_201703/Hedaya#page/n67/mode/2up)
- [الموسوعة الفقهية](https://archive.org/stream/FPmfkmfk/mfk07#page/n176/mode/2up)

Comment: Jazak Allah khayran